# Issue with Redemption embedded in application

Tags: outlook-redemption

We use a product from Epicor, I believe developed by mProof, called Clientele ITSM. The version we are using is 2016.2. We moved to Office 365 and since then are experiencing the error that started with Windows 10 (1809). The error message we receive from the application is:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8000FFFF): System Error.  Code: 18.
>
> There are no more files
>
> at Redemption.ISafeMailItem.SaveAs(String Path, Object Type)
>
> at Clientele.Modules.Attachment.Client.Forms.AttachmentStatusBarPanel.AddEmailAsAttachment(MailItem mitem, Int32 numberOfEmailsSelected)
>
> at Clientele.Modules.Attachment.Client.Forms.AttachmentStatusBarPanel.HandleDragDropEmail()
>
> at Clientele.Modules.Attachment.Client.Forms.AttachmentStatusBarPanel.AttachmentStatusBarPanel_DragDrop(Object sender, DragEventArgs e)

I'm looking to see if there is a way to update the version of Redemption without upgrading the Clientele ITSM application? The DLL appears to be Interop.Redemption.DLL, and the version is 5.15.0.0.

I realize this is a long shot, and the likely correct answer is to upgrade the version of Clientele ITSM, but that is unfortunately not an option at this time.

Thanks for any help or advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Interop.Redemption.DLL` is just a binary header file used by .Net. The files you need to replace are `redemption.dll` and/or `redemption64.dll`. They can be swapped without updating the application that uses it - all versions of Redemption are backward compatible.